# Status calculated column colour code

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, json-formatting, column-formatting

I have a calculated column with this below formula:

```
=IF(ISBLANK([Confirmed Receipt Date]),"Open","Closed")
```

How do I make Open with red color and Closed a green color?

Comment: I found this and hoped it would help me ... I have never used JSON code before. I also had a calculated column with the result of Open or Closed. I copied the code and pasted it to my column formatting section. I couldn't see that it needed me to reference my column name so made no changes to the code.
But on saving and viewing my list I got an error message in the column. What am I doing wrong? See image: [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1KpDt.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1KpDt.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Column/JSON formatting to achieve this. Use below JSON code to change the color of the text:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "debugMode": true,
  "txtContent": "@currentField",
  "style": {
    "color": "=if(@currentField == 'Open', '#ff0000', '#00ff00')"
  }
}
```

**Output**:

[image]

**Documentation**: [Use column formatting to customize SharePoint](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting).

**Additional**:

If you want to change the background color with some cool icons then try below JSON code:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "attributes": {
    "class": "=if(@currentField == 'Close', 'sp-field-severity--good', 'sp-field-severity--blocked') + ' ms-fontColor-neutralSecondary'"
  },
  "children": [
    {
      "elmType": "span",
      "style": {
        "display": "inline-block",
        "padding": "0 8px"
      },
      "attributes": {
        "iconName": "=if(@currentField == 'Close', 'CheckMark', 'ErrorBadge')"
      }
    },
    {
      "elmType": "span",
      "txtContent": "@currentField"
    }
  ]
}
```

It will look like this:

[image]

Comment: Extremely helpful once again, thank you